# sql server check end date is greater than start date

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 columns in my table - start date and end date, which are both nullable. If a value is filled in both, I want to ensure that end date is greater than start date. How do I write a check constraint to do this in SQL server 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something straightforward?

```
WHERE (enddate IS NOT NULL AND startdate IS NOT NULL AND enddate > startdate)
```

Comment: should I add this in `where clause` in the `create table` query? I tried this and it's showing me an error on where syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
Alter table dbo.your_table ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Start_Date_before_End_Date
Check (Start_Date is null OR End_Date is null OR Start_Date < End_Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.yourtable ADD CONSTRAINT CK_yourtable_dates
CHECK (ISNULL(startd, SYSDATETIME) < ISNULL (endd, SYSDATETIME))
```

Comment: in case of NULL it compares to systdate, are you sure that this is was mentioned in the question?

Comment: it wasn't mentioned... but the check constraint is executed every insert/update and according to question should not fail if it is null...

Comment: my original comment is related to your original answer not an edited one with CHECK constraint\

Comment: @Yahia, Thanks for the answer. But I do not want to substitute null values when the dates are null.